# Spring-data-rest and Spring-jpa

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest

data-rest and jpa.

I have created one entity with composite keys using @EmbeddedId

and repository extends CrudRepository with findById query param

when I enter the URL

[a link] (http://localhost:8080/data/person/search/findById?findById=1,2&name=abc)

I'm getting error failed to convert string to Long.

Is there any way of converting string to List of Longs using spring JPA?

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just working on this functionality today, actually.

In the latest snapshot build, there is a new annotation: `@ConvertWith`. You put the class name of a [Spring Core Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) implementation in that annotation and the exporter will use that converter to turn the `String[]` query parameter values into your query method's parameter.

There is an [example of how to use it in your Repository in the tests](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/rest/test/webmvc/PersonRepository.java#L33) (I'll update the wiki shortly but haven't had a chance yet as the ink isn't even dry yet on these new snapshots :). To pass multiple values in a URL query string, you reference the same name multiple times:

```
http://localhost:8080/people/search/findById?id=1&id=2&id=3
```

You can, of course, chose to encode multiple values into a single parameter value (comma-delimited, for instance) and do the conversion in your own converter. You'll still be passed a `String[]` to your custom converter no matter what, though.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks for the reply. We are thinking to use the new annotation. But how soon we can expect the new version release.

Comment: I'm hoping to have the next release ready this week.

Comment: github link for example code does not work